# Error while compiling mDNSResponder on ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to compile `mDNSResponder-320.10.80` on ubuntu 14.04. But I am getting following error. Same has been compiled on fedora successfully. Please suggest me with a possible solution for it.

```
../mDNSShared/dnsextd_parser.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
../mDNSShared/dnsextd_parser.y:188:22: error: ‘context’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    ( ( DaemonInfo* ) context )->private_port = mDNSOpaque16fromIntVal( $3 );
                      ^
../mDNSShared/dnsextd_parser.y:188:22: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../mDNSShared/dnsextd_parser.y: In function ‘ParseConfig’:
../mDNSShared/dnsextd_parser.y:448:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘yyparse’
  err = yyparse( ( void* ) d );
  ^
objects/prod/dnsextd_parser.c:1125:1: note: declared here
 yyparse (void)
 ^
make: *** [objects/prod/dnsextd_parser.y.o] Error 1
```

Br
Gaurav Singla

Comment: Please suggest me if some change change is required in makefile..

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 upgraded to bison 3 which dropped support for YYPARSE_PARAM which had been deprecated a while ago. See news section in: http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7663
This is why dnsextd_parser.y fails on Ubuntu 14.04.

There are a few patches around (search for "patch dnsextd_parser.y") that will make dnsextd_parser.y compatible with bison 3.  I used the one from: http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/net/mDNSResponder/patches/patch-mDNSShared_dnsextd__parser.y

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: This issue is present also in their latest source, mDNSResponder-624.1.2, and this patch seems to work fine.